# Why would the speaker in Rev 21 not be considered Jesus?

Tags: jesus, revelation

I have a NIV Schofield Bible with red letters for the voice of Jesus. Rev 21:5-8 does not have red letters (emphasis mine)

> 5 He who was seated on the throne said, “I am making everything new!” Then he said, “Write this down, for these words are trustworthy and true.”

> 6 He said to me: “It is done. **I am the Alpha and the Omega, the Beginning and the End.** To the thirsty I will give water without cost from the spring of the water of life. 7 Those who are victorious will inherit all this, and I will be their God and they will be my children. 8 But the cowardly, the unbelieving, the vile, the murderers, the sexually immoral, those who practice magic arts, the idolaters and all liars—they will be consigned to the fiery lake of burning sulfur. This is the second death.”

But Rev 22 has two passages that are red. Particularly verses 12-16 (emphasis mine)

> 12 “Look, I am coming soon! My reward is with me, and I will give to each person according to what they have done. 13 **I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End.**

> 14 “Blessed are those who wash their robes, that they may have the right to the tree of life and may go through the gates into the city. 15 Outside are the dogs, those who practice magic arts, the sexually immoral, the murderers, the idolaters and everyone who loves and practices falsehood.

> 16 “I, Jesus, have sent my angel to give you[a] this testimony for the churches. I am the Root and the Offspring of David, and the bright Morning Star.”

They each say the same thing and there is a clear implication that the person in Rev 21 is God. Is there any indication why some scholars would think that person is anyone else?

Comment: The simple answer is that you would need to ask those scholars why, against most conservative Biblical scholarship, they hold a different opinion.  It is not up to this site to defend anybody's opinion who is able to defend it themselves.

Comment: The term "Alpha & Omega" is undistributed, and so need not refer to the same being.

Comment: That Jesus has sent his angel means that he has sent his spirit, since Hebrews indicates that angels are spirits. This in turn could mean that it refers to an out-of-body appearance of Jesus himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "alpha and omega" occurs four times in the NT and only on the Book of Revelation.  It appears to be an extension or explanation of the OT title "First and Last".

- Rev 1:8 - "I am the Alpha and the Omega," says the Lord God, "who is, and who was, and who is to come, the Almighty." - this appears to be applied to God the Father.
- Rev 1:11 - “I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last,” - this is applied to Jesus and only appears in the Byzantine texts and NOT in NA28, etc.
- Rev 21:6 - And He told me, “It is done! I am the Alpha and the Omega, the Beginning and the End. To the thirsty I will give freely from the spring of the water of life. - this is definitely Jesus speaking
- Rev 22:12, 13 - “Behold, I am coming soon, and My reward is with Me, to give to each one according to what he has done. I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End.” - this is definitely Jesus speaking as confirmed by V16 (compare Rev 1:1-3)

The title "first and last" is one of the LORD Jehovah God in the OT (Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12) with "alpha and omega" appears to be the NT equivalent as confirmed by Rev 22:12, 13.  This confirms that the title "first and last" from the OT is applied to Jesus in the NT.

Comment: God is not an offspring of David.(Revelation 22:16) . How is that not plain to those that say Jesus is God. Since when did  God became a creation/offspring of his creation?

Comment: What are your thoughts leading to the conclusion that Rev 1:8 is not a reference to Jesus?

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - this might be the subject of its own question - a case can be made for Rev 1:8 applying to both the Father or the Son.  I personally think the case for the Father is much stronger because of the double -triple accolade first to the Son and then the Father.